# Updating a unique value into an array not working with addToSet

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So here's my schema for Mongoose.

```
  var userSchema = new Schema({

id : {

type: String,
unique: true,
required: true

},
FriendIds:  [

{

type: String,
unique: true 

}


]

});
```

FriendsIds is an array of type String. I want to update values into that array although I do not want to duplicate them. Before you down-vote this, 
yes I have checked other questions on stack and none of them worked for me. I even copied this code straight from mongo documentation and it did not work.

```
User.update({id: req.params.ID}, {$addToSet: {FriendIds: [req.body.friendId]}})    .
```

I'am positive that req.params.ID gives a proper value that is already saved, and that req.body.friendId is a String. However, I cannot get that String to append to the FriendIds. Thank you.

Edit: One thing i forgot to mention is that User = mongoose.model('friend', userSchema);

Comment: shouldn't you be running update against userschema instead of user ? i hope its just a typo ? Have you tried debugging what value userscheam.find({id: req.params.ID}) is returning before performing the update ?

Comment: yes I have it returns a string. User, as you see above, which I should have mentioned is the following:  var User = mongoose.model('friend', userSchema);

Comment: You just use like this
`User.update({id: req.params.ID}, {$addToSet: {FriendIds: req.body.friendId}}) `

Comment: that's exactly what I have in my question and it doesn't work!